# Creating sessions and accessing the variables using Zend_Session_Namespace

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new to the Zend Framework and I have a question regarding creating sessions and accessing the variables using Zend_Session_Namespace.

I guess my question has two parts, first am I creating the session correctly and secondly how can I echo the variable to test if I am doing it correctly.

Part 1
From what I've read this is what I've done.

In my bootstrap file I've created the following function

```
protected function _initSession()
  {
        Zend_Session::start();
        $sessionUserRole = new Zend_Session_Namespace('sessionUserRole');
  }
```

Within my login controller which is based on code I've gotten from Zend Framework a beginners guide I've created a new namespace for the above.

```
// login action
  public function loginAction()
  {

    $form = new PetManager_Form_Login;
    $this->view->form = $form;    

   /* 
   check for valid input from the form and authenticate using adapter
        Add  user record to session and redirect to the original request URL if present
*/
   if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
      $values = $form->getValues();

     $adapter = new PetManager_Auth_Adapter_Doctrine(
       $values['username'], $values['password']
     );
       $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
       $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

     if ($result->isValid()) {
      $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('petmanager.auth');
      $session->user = $adapter->getResultArray('username','Password');
        // $sessionUserRole not Working ?????????          
    $sessionUserRole = new Zend_Session_Namespace('sessionUserRole');
    foreach($this->getRole() as $r)
          {
            $sessionUserRole->userRole = $r['userType'];
    }

      if (isset($session->requestURL)) {
        $url = $session->requestURL;
        unset($session->requestURL);
        $this->_redirect($url);  
      } else {
        $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')
                      ->addMessage('Welcome '.$auth->getIdentity().'. You have been successfully logged in.');
        $this->_redirect('/login/success');
      }
    } else {
      $this->view->message = 'You could not be logged in. Please try again.';          
    }        
    }
    }
   }

 public function getRole()
  {
     $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->select('u.userType')
          ->from('PetManager_Model_Users u')
          ->where('u.name = ?', $values['username']);
     $result = $q->fetchArray();
return $result;
  }
```

Is the code I've written for $sessionUserRole = new Zend_Session_Namespace('sessionUserRole'); correct?? I'm sure its not as when I try to implement it in my users controller to redirect non admin users there is no redirection actioned. I know this can be done through Zend ACL but I want to do it this way and its my first step in learning session_namespace.

Part 2
How can I echo the value of a session variable I've tried 
    $sessionUserRole->userRole;?>
But Im getting nothing.

Sorry I know this is a lot to be asking but I've found that the documentation on this is nearly non existent on the Zend site and what is there is very obtuse, or maybe thats just me :-( .

Comment: Looks "ok" .. what is inside your $_SESSION Global array?

Comment: Where does $values come from in the getRole method? I would suggest adding some debugging code to your foreach loop to see if any roles are being added to the session.

Comment: @ArneRie I'm such a newbie that I'm not sure how to access this in Zend sorry

Comment: @Tim Fountain $values come from my login form so I'm sure that they have a value at least at some point as they allow me to login. But I'll have a look

Comment: $values comes from the form in the login bit, but the getRole function has its own scope and $values is never set (unless it is done in a part of the code you didn't post).

Comment: @Tim Fountain Ok I've change the query to   public function getRole()
  {
  
       $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->select('u.userType')
          ->from('PetManager_Model_Users u')
          ->where('u.name =  "Graham"');
    $result = $q->fetchArray();
 return $result;
  } As I know that this user exists but no joy. I'm being redirected to a a failure page. I've tied to echo out the values of $_Session on this page using <?php foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
echo "$value<br /><br />";
} but all I get displayed is the word Array. Sorry I'm such a newbie

Comment: Try var_dump($_SESSION); instead for debugging

Comment: @Tim Fountain Sorted it god I'm such a tool I added a parameter  to the getRole function and in the login Action I did the following $t=$values['username'];
      foreach($this->getRole($t) as $r)
   { 
       $sessionUserRole->userRole = $r['userType'];
   } This allows me access the page and for lower level users redirects them. Thanks for all your help Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Tims comment, your method getRoles does not have the username for there
sql query.. now we provide it as param to the method.

if you want to access the Session without Zend, just use: `var_dump($_SESSION);`

```
// login action
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $form = new PetManager_Form_Login();
        $this->view->form = $form;

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
                $values = $form->getValues();
                $adapter = new PetManager_Auth_Adapter_Doctrine(
                    $values['username'], $values['password']
                );
                $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
                $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

                if ($result->isValid()) {
                    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('petmanager.auth');
                    $session->user = $adapter->getResultArray('username','Password');
                    $sessionUserRole = new Zend_Session_Namespace('sessionUserRole');

                    // username from form
                    foreach ($this->getRole($values['username']) as $r) {
                        $sessionUserRole->userRole = $r['userType'];
                    }

                    if (isset($session->requestURL)) {
                        $url = $session->requestURL;
                        unset($session->requestURL);
                        $this->_redirect($url);
                    } else {
                        $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->addMessage(
                            'Welcome ' . $auth->getIdentity() .
                            '. You have been successfully logged in.'
                        );
                        $this->_redirect('/login/success');
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->view->message = 'You could not be logged in. Please try again.';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get role for an user
     * 
     * @param string $username User
     * 
     * @return array roles
     */
    public function getRole($username)
    {
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('u.userType')
            ->from('PetManager_Model_Users u')
            ->where('u.name = ?', $username);

        $result = $q->fetchArray();
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: yes your answer is correct I saw the mistake I made from Tims comments and sorted it by adding the param. It was such as stupid mistake on my behalf. I maybe a newbie to Zend but even I should have spotted that.